# Знаки препинания в сложных конструкциях.

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли я расставила знаки препинания в предложении
**В теме** Алфавит **я написала: "Почему   буквы "ерь" и "ер"  по реформе 1918 года получили неуклюжие названия "мягкий знак" и "твёрдый знак,"- и задумалась: а можно ли так сказать:** получили по реформе**?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Знаки препинания в основном расставлены верно. Т.е. все расставлено в соответствии с правилами. Но: получилось целых три двоеточия, так не принято. Хотя бы одно надо заменить на  тире (я бы заменила последнее). Еще я бы взяла в кавычки слово "Алфавит" .